# codewars помощь

Tags: javascript

я практикуюсь на codewars помогите до решить задачу

https://www.codewars.com/kata/5245a9138ca049e9a10007b8/forks/javascript

https://codepen.io/nikitos2004tester/pen/OJMJJJe

> Функция f1 подсчитывает количество разделов, повторяющих одно и то же
>   слово (без учета регистра). Вхождение двух или более одинаковых слов,
>   следующих друг за другом, считается одним.

```
function f1(text){
    let counter=null
    let up1=text.toUpperCase()
    let uparray=up1.split(' ')
    console.log(uparray)
    let array=new Set(uparray)
    console.log(array)

    counter=uparray.length-array.size
}

f1("cat cat dog dog cat cat")
```

Comment: _"Вхождение двух или более одинаковых слов, следующих друг за другом, считается одним."_ - вот этого в твоём коде вообще нет.

Comment: ваш `split` не сработает [скрин](http://prntscr.com/ssgv4y)

Comment: так я прошу помощи

Comment: @никита так я вам показал как я сделал, как другие сделали ( с пояснениями для разбора) какой помощи вам еще нужно?

Answer (score 1):

Так решил это я:

```js
// Тестовый массив
testArray = [
  "dog cat",                
  "dog DOG cat",            
  "apple dog cat",          
  "pineapple apple dog cat",
  "apple     apple dog cat",
  "apple dog apple dog cat",
  "dog dog DOG dog dog dog",
  "dog dog dog dog cat cat",
  "cat cat dog dog cat cat"
];

// Запускаю тест
testArray.forEach(testString => console.log(countAdjacentPairs(testString)))

// искомый метод
function countAdjacentPairs(searchString) {
  // счетчик
  var count = 0;
  // прошлое слово
  var curStr = "";
  // итерировали ли мы уже это слово?
  var coincidences = false;
  
  // если строка пуста возвращаем 0
  if (searchString.length === 0) return 0;
  // разбиваем строку по проблам ( пробелов может быть от 1 и больше)
  searchString.toLowerCase().split(new RegExp(' +', 'g')).forEach(str => {
    // Если прошлое слово совпало с текущим и мы его еще не итерировали, то увеличиваем счетчик
    if (str === curStr && !coincidences){
      count++;
      coincidences = true;
    }
    // Если слово не совпадает но итератор включен - то убираем итератор
    if (str !== curStr && coincidences){
      coincidences = false;
    }
    curStr = str;
  });
  // возвращаю счетчик
  return count;
}
```

Несколько решений с codewar:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `.split(/\s+/)`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME сапсибо, та с головы вылетило какая именно буква..

Comment: `\s` - space, `\d` - digit, `\w` - word )

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME пасибо, не знал этого )